# What does the values of Position under apache kafka partiton log?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

What does the values of the position under the below log file mean?

```
Starting offset: 0
offset: 0 position: 0 CreateTime: 1541783974960 isvalid: true keysize: -1 valuesize: 10 magic: 2 compresscodec: NONE producerId: -1 producerEpoch: -1 sequence: -1 isTransactional: false headerKeys: [] payload: Spam_Mail1
offset: 1 position: 78 CreateTime: 1541784566896 isvalid: true keysize: -1 valuesize: 0 magic: 2 compresscodec: NONE producerId: -1 producerEpoch: -1 sequence: -1 isTransactional: false headerKeys: [] payload: 
offset: 2 position: 146 CreateTime: 1541784725893 isvalid: true keysize: -1 valuesize: 0 magic: 2 compresscodec: NONE producerId: -1 producerEpoch: -1 sequence: -1 isTransactional: false headerKeys: [] payload:
```

Comment: I *think*, it's the position with the record-batch.

Answer (score 2):

The position attribute represents the ***physical*** position of the message in the segment log file.

The same attribute is also available in the position index file along with the offset.

When a consumer sends a fetch request for a message at offset *x*, the brokers looks for the offset closest to offset *x* in the index file, takes the position value from that index file and goes to that ***position in the log file*** (the one you are referring to in your question) to fetch the message.

Hope this helps!